# How do I split by commas, then sections surrounded by double quotes?

Tags: python

I have a file "data.txt" with lines such as

```
4, "124 Sesame, Street Lane", Chicago, IL
5, 2342 Main Street, Denver, CO
6, 124 Some Street, Los Angelos, CA
```

I have a python script that reads this file line by line and splits it up into a tuple of data in the form `(id, street address, city, state)`. The script splits each line up by commas:

```
line = file.readline()
line_tuple = line.split(',')
```

This method clearly breaks down because I have some lines that have chunks of text surrounded by double quotes that I want to consider as a whole entity in the tuple as opposed to two distinct pieces of data.

How do I tell python to treat blocks of double quotes a single entity when splitting by commas?

I have tried splitting by quotes first and then commas and vice versa, but these methods don't seem to get at what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a real [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) parser. [Python 2](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html), [Python 3](http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)

```
# default delimiter is , and default quotechar is "
>>> import csv
>>> with open('eggs.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
...     spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
...     for row in spamreader:
...         print(', '.join(row))
Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Baked Beans
Spam, Lovely Spam, Wonderful Spam
```

Answer (score 2):

That is called a "comma separated values" or short "csv". Python has a library for reading it.

Check out: http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html or http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html if you are using Python 3.